# will my geth fast synching for mainnet ever catch up?

Tags: ethereum, geth

I'm using AMD Ryzen 7 2700x CPU, 64Gb memory 1Tb SSD, 100Mb Internet downspeed configuration to create a Ethereum node. I'm running the geth synchmode "fast" command to build a node but it seems to never catch up ! What numbers should I be looking at to see if it ever will. I've read  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20962 so I know that block count isn't really what I should look for ? Is there something else whose rate of change I should monitor to see if I'm catching up ?  e.g. pulled states in the output from the eth.synching command ? or the pending number in the log entry detailing the Imported new state entries ?
My geth command:

```
geth --syncmode "fast" --cache=4096 -llow-insecure-unlock --http --datadir /crypto/ethereum/mainnet --keystore /crypto/ethereum/keystore --signer=/crypto/ethereum/clef.ipc --maxpeers 25 2>/crypto/ethereum/mainnet_sync_r5.log
```

Output from eth.synching:

> eth.syncing
> {   currentBlock: 12168062,
> highestBlock: 12168171,
> knownStates: 183392940,
> pulledStates: 183343841,
> startingBlock: 12160600 }

last few lines from my command log:

> INFO [04-03|11:16:04.511] Imported new state entries count=1350 elapsed=7.456ms
> processed=183847128 pending=53248 trieretry=93   coderetry=0 duplicate=2969 unexpected=4186274

> INFO [04-03|11:16:04.674] Imported new state entries               count=0
> elapsed=4.487ms     processed=183847128 pending=52401  trieretry=93   coderetry=0 duplicate=2969 unexpected=4186367

> INFO[04-03|11:16:04.681] Imported new state entries
> count=1059 elapsed=6.784ms     processed=183848187 pending=52401
> trieretry=93   coderetry=0 duplicate=2969 unexpected=4186367

> INFO [04-03|11:16:04.880] Imported new state entries
> count=1152 elapsed=5.161ms     processed=183849339 pending=53150
> trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=2969 unexpected=4186367

> INFO [04-03|11:16:05.003] Imported new state entries
> count=1152 elapsed=5.906ms     processed=183850491 pending=52394
> trieretry=0    coderetry=0 duplicate=2969 unexpected=4186367

Comment: It should catch up in one day https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513